# If G be a non-trivial group with no non-trivial proper subgroup, show that G is a group of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

**If G be a non-trivial group with no non-trivial proper subgroup, show that G is a group of prime order.**

Attempt:

Given $G\neq \{e\}$ and let $a\in G, a\neq e$.
Then $H=<a>$ is a subgroup of G. Then by the hypothesis, $H= \{e\} ~or~ G$. But $H\neq <a>, ~as ~a\neq e$.
So G is generated by $a$.

I can show also that G is finite (if G is infinite, considering group $<a^2>$).

> Let if possible, $o(G)=n=composite=kl, ~k,l>1$ are intergers. As $G=<a>$, $o(a)=n$. As $<a^k>$ is a subgroup of G, $(a^k)^l=a^{kl}=a^n=e\implies o(a^k)=l<n$, i.e $<a^k>$ is a subgroup of order $<n$, but G cannot have a non-trivial subgroup. So $l=1 ~or~ l=n$. How to conclude the rest?

The problem is in the shaded portion only. Please correct it.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Do not have the time to find it now. BTW it is easy to show the finiteness and then apply Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: @NickyHekster The problem is in the shaded portion only.

Comment: It could be better written, but the shaded portion is correct as it is. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @ArnaudD. $<a^k>$ is a subgroup of order <n. Upto this is clear to me. Need the rest part to show n is not composite.

Comment: Note: $(a^k)^l=e$ implies $o(a^k)\color{red}{\le}l$, not $o(a^k)=l$.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Would you please write the rest part then. How to prove n is not composite then?

Comment: @user1942348 Since $(a^k)^l=e$ and $l<n$, $\langle a^k\rangle$ is a proper subgroup and so $a^k=e$; but $k<n$, contradicting the fact that $o(a)=n$.